# Core Data - undoing changes after saving a context

Tags: ios, core-data, nsundomanager

I've recently noticed this strange thing about undo mechanism in Core Data and it's bothering me ever since.

A quote from `NSManagedObjectContext` documentation for `-undo` method:

> Sends an undo message to the receiver’s undo manager, asking it to reverse the latest uncommitted changes applied to objects in the object graph.

To reverse *the latest uncommitted changes*, sounds simple, right?

However, it's not what is actually happening! Even if I save the context with changes on my managed object, the following `-undo` call will still successfully reverse the changes. Isn't it against the thing stated in the docs?

Perhaps I'm doing something wrong? I can post my little testing code if needed. I'm really confused.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You *should* be confused. The Core Data documentation is a hot mess. They use a lot of words like "uncommitted" in arguably inappropriate ways. They seem to mean objects whose properties `isFaulted` is equal to NO when they say "uncommitted".

The Core Data Programming guide goes into more detail:

> ### Change and Undo Management
>
> A context keeps strong references to managed objects that have pending
>   changes (insertions, deletions, or updates) until the context is sent
>   a save:, reset , rollback, or dealloc message, or the appropriate
>   number of undos to undo the change.
>
> The undo manager associated with a context keeps strong references to
>   any changed managed objects. By default, in OS X the context’s undo
>   manager keeps an unlimited undo/redo stack. **To limit your
>   application's memory footprint, you should make sure that you scrub
>   (using `removeAllActions`) the context’s undo stack as and when
>   appropriate**. Unless you keep a strong reference to a context’s undo
>   manager, it is deallocated with its context.

The wording/vocabulary in the documentation is not clear or consistent. I believe the intended usage is that the you should call `removeAllActions` on the context's `undoManager` property when appropriate for your application to avoid unlimited memory growth.

Comment: Well, I guess it makes sense... Still, it's a pity they didn't pay much attention to the wording. The whole Core Data undo management feels like a bit of magic and hence needs a good and thoughtful explanation.

Comment: I edited my answer with their definition of "uncommitted". It took me a while to figure out why they would ever even use that word.